# formData sent from Firefox/Chrome but not sent from iOS

Tags: react-native, google-chrome, axios, expo, multipartform-data

I'm building a React-native/Expo app and testing it on web and mobile (via Expo Go). In my app I'm making an Axios call (which sends `formData`) to an API endpoint I have. When I run my app in Firefox or Chrome, everything is fine but when I run it on iOS, the `formData` doesn't get to the endpoint.

Before I make the request, I'm logging out my `fileBlob` and `filename` as well as `formData` and it looks different in Chrome and in iOS. In iOS it looks like this:
[image: ios formdata]

Whereas in Chrome it looks like this:
[image]

The code where I'm forming this `formData` and the request are here:

```
const getFileName = (filePath) => {
    return filePath.split("/").pop();
};

export const transcribe = async (uri: string): Promise<string> => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    const file = await fetch(uri);
    const fileBlob = await file.blob();
    const filename = getFileName(uri);
    formData.append("audioFile", fileBlob, filename);
    console.log({ fileBlob, filename });
    console.log({ formData });

    try {
        const {
            data: {
                session: { access_token: token },
            },
            error,
        } = await supabase.auth.getSession();

        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post(
            `${clientUrl}/api/transcribe`,
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
            }
        );

        return data.transcription;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return "";
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to load the `formData` different in different places? Is React-native doing some black magic here?